# Print shell's time command results, when running program with python script

Tags: python, linux, shell, time

I am trying to use python to run program several times and write the output in a file. I am executing this simple code to test, where *clwb* is a compiled program file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import time, call,DEVNULL,STDOUT,check_output,CalledProcessError
import shlex

with open("results/output.csv", 'w') as csvfile:

    command_to_execute="time ./clwb"
    call(shlex.split(command_to_execute),stdout=DEVNULL,stderr=STDOUT)
    result=check_output(shlex.split(command_to_execute), universal_newlines=True)
    csvfile.write(result+" \n")
```

I am executing this python program with python3 command in lunux. However in the file I only get the output of the program itself, but not the result of the *time* command, which if executed directly from the shell, at the end of the output of the program, prints something like this:

```
real    0m0.813s
user    0m1.140s
sys     0m0.056s
```

And this result is the most important for me, as I am trying to evaluate execution time of the process itself.

I am not even a beginner in python, and this is the only code I have dealt with before, so I have no idea what might be the reason why I don't see the result of *time* command in the file, which I suppose should be doable, and especially how to solve this issue.

**UPDATE:** solved by modifying the following line

```
result=check_output(shlex.split(command_to_execute), stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
```

Comment: What is the output from 'type time'? What happens when you call `/usr/bin/time` instead of just `time`?

Comment: from shell directly, it prints this: 1.14user 0.07system 0:00.82elapsed ... However when added in script, I still don't see this in the file. It's not written.

Comment: I tried now but it gives this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'STDERR'

Comment: Yes, my fault, sorry. Please try `/usr/bin/time` in your python program.

Comment: I tried but it still does not work. I don't get it's result in the file.

Comment: Otherwise, try `"bash -c 'time ./clwb'"` in your python program.

Comment: in documentation for [call_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) you can see *To also capture standard error in the result, use stderr=subprocess.STDOUT:* Maybe `time` use `stderr` to display it.

Comment: @Roadowl I did that. Now I get the result printed in shell, not in the file, but I want those results in the file, because I will run several times and I want them collected in one file, if possible

Comment: @furas yes, this seems to work. I get the result 1.12user 0.04system 0:00.81elapsed in the file as well. Thank you very much. Well if not asking too much, it there any way, I can get this result in file as nice as it prints in shell? I mean the version I have provided in the question, real ....

Comment: you could use python to reformat it ;) As I know first version is created by bash built-in command `time`, and it is not external program `/usr/bin/time`. You would have to use `bash` and `time`.

Comment: @furas :D ok, well this version is still better than not having any execution time results in file, so I am happy with this as well. again thank you very much

Comment: [BashFAQ #32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032) is relevant.